# Unable to click on an element using CssSelector and Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I open this site in python https://zeitung.faz.net/ when open a message in popup this site

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#notice > div.message-component.message-row.sticky-element > div.message-component.message-row.row-no-margin-phone.cta-yep > div").click()
```

but not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element <kbd>ZUSTIMMEN</kbd> is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    driver.get('https://zeitung.faz.net/')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[title='SP Consent Message']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[title='ZUSTIMMEN']"))).click()
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    driver.get('https://zeitung.faz.net/')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@title='SP Consent Message']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@title='ZUSTIMMEN']"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: still get error for driver
    driver=webdriver.chrome()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Works perfect at my end. On which line what error do you see?

Comment: when run it
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` have nothing to do with this lines of code and sounds to be some issue else where in program setup.